# Texture/Material not exporting to Unity correctly

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I've been learning how to export textures from Blender to Unity, however upon exporting the model and texture separately, I notice that the textures don't look correct in Unity. To get the model and the texture into Unity I export the model as fbx, then UV wrap the model and bake it into an image file.

Texture in Blender vs Unity:

[image]

[image]

The texture looks less detailed and a lot lighter. I'm not sure if it has to do with lighting or export settings. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the blend file: [image]